# How to use multiple conditions in a for loop in a function?

Tags: python, multiple-conditions

I'm still new to python and have just started learning. The task given is to find the amount of punctuation, vowels, and constants in a given text. But whenever I run the code it just gives me a `0`.

```
def getInfo(text):

    pun = [".", ",", " ", "\'", "\"", "!"]
    vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]

    count = 0
    count2 = 0
    count3 = 0
    for char in text:
        if char in pun:
           count += 1
        return count
    
        if char.lower() in vowels:
           count2 += 1
        return count2
        
        if (not char.lower() in vowels) and (not char.lower() in pun):      
            count3 += 1
        return count3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return should be outside the loop.

It should be :

```
def getInfo(text):

    pun = [".", ",", " ", "\'", "\"", "!"]
    vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]

    count = 0
    count2 = 0
    count3 = 0
    for char in list(text):
        if char in pun:
           count += 1
   
        if char.lower() in vowels:
           count2 += 1
        
        if (not char.lower() in vowels) and (not char.lower() in pun):      
            count3 += 1
    return (count, count2, count3)

getInfo('myname.is hello world!')

# (4, 6, 12)
```

Answer (score 1):

When program reaches return it exits from loop.

```
def getInfo(text):

    pun = [".", ",", " ", "'", '"', "!"]
    vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]

    count = 0
    count2 = 0
    count3 = 0
    for char in text:
        if char in pun:
            count += 1

        if char.lower() in vowels:
            count2 += 1

        if (not char.lower() in vowels) and (not char.lower() in pun):
            count3 += 1
    return "count: {0}, count2: {1}, count3: {2}".format(count, count2, count3)

print(getInfo("We are in 2020."))
```

Output:

```
count: 4, count2: 4, count3: 7
```

Answer (score 1):

You are retuning value after checking punctuation, rest of them are ignored. So you are getting 0. Your code is valid for punctuation check.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `return` keyword, that's, all the code below will not run and the function will returns the variable `count`.

Please, verify this.